# Eloquent relation WHERE statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all 'Holidays' combined with 'HolidayInfo' which are the respective table names.

This is the query i'm attempting to use:

```
    $holidays = Holidays::with('info')->where('country', $country)->get();
```

When using this query; I get the following error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `holidays` where `country` = australia)"
```

It seems as if the join has not been performed. Even when giving writing 'holiday_info.country' it still doesn't work as expected.

When doing a vardump of         `$holidays = Holidays::with('info')->get();` I get this:

[image]

Here it is evident that a relationship is being established but is not included in the query.

Here are the tables in use:

[image]
[image]

My Eloquent Models:

**Holiday**

```
protected $table = 'holidays';
protected $primaryKey = 'holiday_id';
public $timestamps = false;
public $incrementing = false;
public function info(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\HolidayInfo', 'holiday_id','holiday_id');
}
```

**Holiday Info:**

```
protected $table = 'holiday_info';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = null;
public $incrementing = false;
public function holidays(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Holiday', 'holiday_id', 'holiday_id');
}
```

I'm not sure why the connection between both tables isn't working in the top query. It seems as if country isnt recognised as a field in holiday_info hence showing the join isnt being completed correctly. Any ideas what the issue may be?

Comment: you use wrong column name('country') check try again
in holiday_info table there is a column called country

Comment: Hi @GauravGupta the table is there displayed for you to see. The country is spelt correct.

Comment: Try to remove one `holiday_id` from `Holiday Info` model  in `belongsTo` statement.Then try it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it code might help you

```
$holidays = Holidays::whereHas('info', function($info) use($country){
    $info->where('country', $country);              
})->get();
```

[Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Well done - Whats the difference between WhereHas and with?

Comment: `whereHas` and `with` are completely different. `with` is used for eager-loading and `whereHas` is used on relations to check for existence.

Answer (score 0):

try this method. You have to use function to join and use where condition in it

```
$holidays = Holidays::with(['info' => function($query) use($country){
            $query->where('country', $country);
         } ])->get();
```

Comment: Hi there, Unfortunately it still doesnt work because when I make `$country = 'dadadasdas'` it still returns every row (when each row doesnt have that entry)

Comment: Have you added `use($country)` in query?

Comment: Yes. Even if i make it `->where('country', 'dadasdsa');` it shows all entries